# Exact result in Google Query, followed by partial match if exact result does not exist

Tags: google-sheets, google-query-language

I'm using Google Query to search a Google Spreadsheet: https://jsfiddle.net/BaronGrivet/ctkpvuac/3/

Example Data:

```
Block Hill Road
Greenhill Road
Hill Road
Brownhill Road
```

Example Query:

```
'SELECT A WHERE LOWER(A) LIKE "%'+searchInput+'%" ORDER BY A ASC'
```

If someone searches for "Hill" it will return all of the rows.

However if someone searches for "Hill Road" it will still return all of the rows with "Hill Road" listed last.

Ideally I want it to either only return the exact match "Hill Road", or at least have "Hill Road" as the first response.

Is there a way to structure the query so that exact matches are either only shown or shown first?

Or would I have to script a fallback where I first query for an exact match and if that's not returned I query a partial match?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a step in the right direction:

```
={query(A:A,"select * where LOWER(A) LIKE 'hill road%' ORDER BY A desc");query(A:A,"select * where LOWER(A) LIKE '%hill road%' ORDER BY A desc")}
```

to give the order:

```
Hill Road
Hill Road
Greenhill Road
Brownhill Road
Block Hill Road
```

(the exact match is duplicated), or possibly prepend a space to all entries in ColumnA and apply:

```
={query(A:A,"select * where LOWER(A) LIKE '% hill road%' ORDER BY A desc");query(A:A,"select * where LOWER(A) LIKE '%hill road%' ORDER BY A desc")}
```

to give:

```
 Hill Road
 Block Hill Road
 Hill Road
 Greenhill Road
 Brownhill Road
 Block Hill Road
```

If you would rather not have the 'exact' and 'similar' duplicated then wrap in UNIQUE:

(a) without added spaces:

```
=unique({query(A:A,"select * where LOWER(A) LIKE '% hill road%' ORDER BY A desc");query(A:A,"select * where LOWER(A) LIKE '%hill road%' ORDER BY A desc")})
```

output:

```
Hill Road
Greenhill Road
Brownhill Road
Block Hill Road
```

(b) with added spaces:

```
=unique({query(A:A,"select * where LOWER(A) LIKE '% hill road%' ORDER BY A desc");query(A:A,"select * where LOWER(A) LIKE '%hill road%' ORDER BY A desc")})
```

output:

```
 Hill Road
 Block Hill Road
 Greenhill Road
 Brownhill Road
```

If choosing UNIQUE order `asc` may make better sense.

Comment: Thank you. Could you show me the syntax for wrapping in UNIQUE?

Comment: unfortunately I'm getting an "invalid query" response: https://jsfiddle.net/BaronGrivet/jronLh38/1/ from sending this query ```=unique({query(A:A, "SELECT A WHERE LOWER(A) LIKE 'hill road%' ORDER BY A ASC LIMIT 10");query(A:A, "SELECT A WHERE LOWER(A) LIKE '%hill road%' ORDER BY A ASC LIMIT 10")})``` - which works fine in the spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SPpZQ3KolUOI2GxNz4yvuAr5-5DFi2yMQEaQ0efNJJ0/edit#gid=0