# Making a query formula search box with partial match

Tags: google-sheets, formula

Thanks in advance to all,
I have a spreadsheet with multiple sheets. I want my master sheets to have a search box based on a query that is referencing from a cell( my case A1)

*iv managed to accomplish this, but the search results are only exact match.
can someone help please how can make it a partial match instead of exact or even combined the two.

**iv tried this thread but it doesn't work, maybe I'm doing something wrong
thanks:

**[Exact result in Google Query, followed by partial match if exact result does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44752790/exact-result-in-google-query-followed-by-partial-match-if-exact-result-does-not)**

- this is the query that is working right now

  =QUERY({sheet1!A2:I24;'sheet2'!A2:I26;'sheet3'!A2:I26},"select Col1, Col2, Col4,Col7,Col9 where Col1 = '"&A1&"'",1)

Cheers to all,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [reference](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage):

> `like` - A text search that supports two wildcards: `%`, which matches
>   zero or more characters of any kind, and `_` (underscore), which matches
>   any one character. This is similar to the SQL LIKE operator. Example:
>   `where name like fre% matches 'fre', 'fred', and 'freddy'`

`where Col1 like '%"&A1&"%'"`

Another, more powerful approach is to use `filter` + `regexmatch`:

`=filter({sheet1!A2:I24;'sheet2'!A2:I26;'sheet3'!A2:I26},
regexmatch({sheet1!A2:A24;'sheet2'!A2:A26;'sheet3'!A2:A26}, A1))`

See more on regex syntax [here](https://github.com/google/re2/blob/master/doc/syntax.txt).

The result of a filter may be a query data source:

`=query(filter(..., ...), "select Col1, ...")`

Comment: you are a magician my friend thank you so much that works perfect cheers, have a great week end :))